# Read full stdin until EOF when stdin comes from `cat` bash

Tags: bash, stdin, cat

I'm trying to read full stdin into a variable :

## script.sh

```
#/bin/bash

input=""
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  input="$input""\n""$line"
done < /dev/stdin



echo "$input" > /tmp/test
```

When I run `ls | ./script.sh` or mostly any other commands, it works fine.

However It doesn't work when I run `cat | ./script.sh` , enter my message, and then hit Ctrl-C to exit cat.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why use a loop? Can't you use `IFS= read -r -d '' variable` ?

Comment: Normally, control-D is set to send EOF from the keyboard, not control-C.

Comment: @user000001 : I didn't know about that, thanks

Comment: Oh right, with C-d it works fine ! Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would stick to the one-liner

```
input=$(cat)
```

Of course, `Ctrl-D` should be used to signal end-of-file.